Can not send audio answer back on call using Websocket when creating IVR with Twilio
I have been working on one project recently, structure's literaly the same as this tutorial:here. On Media message part I'm trying to give back real-time audio answer from chatbot, but i literaly can`t receive anything. I tried modifiy code for send_raw_data like this
def send_raw_audio(file_path, ws, stream_sid):
    audio_data = []
    with wave.open(file_path, 'rb') as wav_file:
        while True:
            wav_data = wav_file.readframes(320)
            if not wav_data:
                break

            mulaw_data = audioop.lin2ulaw(wav_data, 2)
            base64_audio = base64.b64encode(mulaw_data).decode("utf-8")
            audio_data.append(base64_audio)

    return audio_data

and i tried send anything with ws.send.
The point is,it's never answers with the voice when I am inside connected ws socket. I`m out of ideas, maybe someone had this problem before? I tried VoiceResponse, Say and everything is not working inside /stream def. I have wavfile with the audio i want to play, it's saved only on my local computer
